# Auto-completion for option values in user-defined functions

Tags: options, autocomplete

In [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OptionsPattern.html), and all it's closely related links, I cant find anything that tells me how to set a list of the optional arguments.

All I want is something like this

```
Options[myfunc] = { a->0 };
myfunc[x_,OptionsPattern[]]:=Block[....]
```

Say, by default, a is 0. How do I setup something like when I use

```
myfunc[100, a->
```

would trigger a drop down list of values, {0,10,100,True,False} for me to choose?

I would think it can be easily found in the link above, or some of the links on its page. But it's just nowhere to be found!

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. v10 introduced autocompletion for builtin string options, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to register your own autocompletions.

Comment: Side note: options are not the same as [optional arguments](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionalAndDefaultArguments.html).  Changed the tags accordingly.