# How to define OptionsPattern with autocompletion?

Tags: options

I wish to define a custom function having optional parameters.
Usually, OptionsPattern[] meets my requirements, but I would like to build the function similar to embedding ones, which after typing "Parameter" -> generate an autocompletion list with all options of this parameters. Is it possible?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Auto-completion for option values in user-defined functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/67377/9490)

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78935/prompt-a-set-of-possible-options/82697#82697

Comment: Related but not the same: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56984/argument-completions-for-user-defined-functions

Comment: As I see, custom's autocompletion capacity is not implemented in **Mathematica** yet. Different users at their own risk apply various workarounds. But solutions are version-dependent and can results in unstable performance of software.